# Finding the sum of leaves in a Binary tree using nodes

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I want to be able to recursively find the sum of all the leaves in a binary tree through the use of nodes so far I have:

```
class BTNode:
  """A node in a binary tree."""

  def __init__(self: 'BTNode', item: object, 
               left: 'BTNode' =None, right: 'BTNode' =None) -> None:
    """Initialize this node.
    """
    self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'BTNode({}, {}, {})'.format(repr(self.item), 
                    repr(self.left), repr(self.right))

  def is_leaf(self: 'BTNode') -> bool:
    return not self.left and not self.right


def tree_sum(t: BTNode) -> int:
  '''Return the sum of the leaves in t.

  >>> t = BTNode(None, BTNode(8), BTNode(9))
  >>> tree_sum(t)
  17
  '''
  sm = 0
  t1 = t.left.item
  t2 = t.right.item
  if not t.left or not t.right:
    return 0
  if t.left.is_leaf() and t.right.is_leaf():
    sm = t1 + t2 + tree_sum(t.left) + tree_sum(t.right)
  return sm
```

The function tree_sum(t) I have doesn't work, I'm struggling to find a way that works. What am i doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a tiny bit of code.

Since `t.left` and `t.right` will be `None` if `t` is a leaf, the lines `t1 = t.left.item` and `t2 = t.right.item` will raise an `AttributeError`.

You need to take that into account:

```
t1 = t.left.item if t.left else None
t2 = t.right.item if t.right else None
```

Then

```
t = BTNode(None, BTNode(8), BTNode(9))
print(tree_sum(t))
```

produces the correct result (17).

**That said**, this function will *not* return the sum of all leaves (ie it won't traverse the whole tree in case of a multi-level tree).